# how to access to OpenShift V3 database from external

Tags: ssh, openshift

I've migrated my J2EE/MySQL applications from OpenShift V2 to V3. In the old installation I was able to connect to the database with a SSH connection. So I had an online backup service in place to do the work automatically.

For admin purposes I've created a port-forwarding and connected with the local tools to the database

How can I connect in V3 from external without port-forwarding?

Comment: If you are using OpenShift Online, you can't as you require cluster admin access to expose non HTTP services, and in Online you don't have such access.

Comment: [NodePort](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_nodeport.html) is an option if you have cluster admin access.